# Python help for Loop

Tags: python, loops

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of studen heights ").split()

total_height = 0
for height in student_heights:
  total_height += height
print(total_height)

number_of_students = 0
for student in student_heights:
  number_of_students += 1
print(number_of_students)
```

---

Im following with the teacher on a online course and I don't see what im doing wrong.

the error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    total_height += height
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Make sure both are `int`. One is a `str`.

Comment: `student_heights = input("Input a list of studen heights ").split()` ->  `student_heights = list(map(int,input("Input a list of studen heights ").split()))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `total_height` variable is a number, but your `height` variable is a string, because the `input()` function returns a string. In order to add these two variables, you must first convert `height` to a integer with `int(height)`. Like this:

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of studen heights ").split()

total_height = 0
for height in student_heights:
  total_height += int(height)
print(total_height)

number_of_students = 0
for student in student_heights:
  number_of_students += 1
print(number_of_students)
```

Alternatively, you can convert the `student_heights` list into a list of numbers from the beginning with `map()`. This might make your code a bit more intuitive. Like this:

```
student_heights = map(int, input("Input a list of studen heights ").split())

total_height = 0
for height in student_heights:
  total_height += height
print(total_height)

number_of_students = 0
for student in student_heights:
  number_of_students += 1
print(number_of_students)
```